# reactjs: material-table: how to do serverside validation when adding or editing

Tags: material-table

I am planning to use `material-table`. Its a simple table with a column `name`

I have seen some tutorials how to do CRUD operation using material-table.

But i want to check the name is unique from server side, not on client side.

and pass the error if the name is not unique.

Can we do these things with material table

Comment: Material-UI etc are client-side components. Server-side validation depends upon the language you use to write your server backend. So what language do you use for your server side?

Comment: I am asking about how to show server side errors. which are recieved as json